# JQuery/Javascript: begin and end dates in an array, end date has to be greater than begin date

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, validation

Hi all,

I’m building a web to book a common room.

It has a form with a begin date field and an ending date field.

You can add as many beginning dates an ending dates as you want.

When the data is submitted I have an array with all the beginning dates and another array with all the ending dates.

To clarify:

```
Begin dates             Ending dates
01-07-2013              03-07-2013
04-07-2013              10-07-2013

arrayBeginDates ["01-07-2013","04-07-2013"]

arrayEndDates ["03-07-2013","10-07-2013"]
```

The way the arrays a formed in my code:

```
var arrayBeginDates = [];
$(".beginDate").each(function(){
    arrayBeginDates.push($(this).val());
})

//and the same for ending dates, arrayEndDates
```

I need to validate that in the pairs begin-end dates the end date is greater than the begin date.

Meaning:

arrayEndDates [0] has to be greater than arrayBeginDates [0] otherwise error alert and exit
arrayEndDates [1] has to be greater than arrayBeginDates [1] otherwise error alert and exit

and so on

How can I do that??

Thanks a ton!

Comment: can your date be less than today dates .i.e whatever  date will today ,is there chances to get dates below that

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bDates = ["01-07-2013","04-07-2013"];
var eDates = ["03-07-2013","10-07-2013"];

for (var i = 0; i < bDates.length; i++) {
   if ((new Date(eDates[i].split('-').reverse().join(','))) > (new Date(bDates[i].split('-').reverse().join(',')))) {
      console.log('valid');
   } else {
      console.log('invaid');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

```
arrayBeginDates.each( function(index, beginDate) {
    var begin = new Date(beginDate).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var end = new Date(arrayEndDates[index]).setHours(0,0,0,0);

    if (begin > end)
        //handle Error
});
```

*Note*: This requires that arrayStartDates and arrayEndDates have the same number of elements (but then, your question doesn't make much sense if they don't).